# How do I display a javascript value in dropdown field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a trivial ask but I can't seem to work it out elegantly. I have an HTML form where I want to display the date (today & next 2 days, dd/mm) using javascript. The page is built on jQueryMobile.

Here's my HTML

```
<form>
<select name="departure" id="departure">
        <option ><script>document.write(today);</script></option>
        <option ><script>document.write(tomorrow);</script></option>
        <option ><script>document.write(dayaftertomorrow);</script></option>
</select>
</form>
```

Here's my Javascript

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 
today = dd+'/'+mm;

//---------- 
var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000);
var day = tomorrow.getDate()
var month = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1
if(day<10) {
    day='0'+day
} 
if(month<10) {
    month='0'+month
} 
tomorrow = day+'/'+month

//---------- 
var aftertomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 172800000);
var afterday = aftertomorrow.getDate()
var aftermonth = aftertomorrow.getMonth() + 1
if(afterday<10) {
    afterday='0'+afterday
} 
if(aftermonth<10) {
    aftermonth='0'+aftermonth
} 
aftertomorrow = afterday+'/'+aftermonth
```

Here's [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toutgreg/S8HZV/)

How would you go about this ?

Thanks
Greg

Comment: Yeah, see, `document.write` just isn't a good idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: Omit the `dw()` and set `option.text`s instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/S8HZV/1/

I added an id to the options and I added 3 more lines to the script.
Try using innerHTML instead of document.write.

HTML:

```
<form>
<select name="departure" id="departure">
    <option id="today"></option>
    <option id="tomorrow"></option>
    <option id="dayaftertomorrow"></option>
</select>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('today').innerHTML= today;
document.getElementById('tomorrow').innerHTML= tomorrow;
document.getElementById('dayaftertomorrow').innerHTML= aftertomorrow;
```

Comment: Thanks for that Mark.
Probably stating the obvious, but when you add these lines to your code, make sure the JS comes after your form... Otherwise, there's nowhere to load the date into !

Answer (score 1):

You can create the option elements and insert them into the select with javascript.

For example, this is how you would add today as an option to the departure select

```
 var select = document.getElementById('departure');
 var option = document.createElement('option');
 option.innerHTML = today;
 select.appendChild(option);
```

Answer (score 1):

For another option, this sets the value, too.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/S8HZV/5/

```
document.getElementById('departure').options[0].val = today;
document.getElementById('departure').options[0].text = today;

document.getElementById('departure').options[1].val = tomorrow;
document.getElementById('departure').options[1].text = tomorrow;

document.getElementById('departure').options[2].val = aftertomorrow;
document.getElementById('departure').options[2].text = aftertomorrow;
```

Comment: Guess it's more cross-browser compliant. Good to know !